# Deleting/ removing an item from a list in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to delete an individual item from a list in my Javascript app using Firebase and I'm having a lot of difficulty at the moment. The code below is just a very simplified version of it.

```
var itemList = document.getElementById("itemList");

window.onload = function () {
   queryData();
}

function queryData() {

   return databaseRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {

        itemList.innerHTML +=
            "<li>"
            + snapshot.child("title").val() + "&nbsp" +
            <!-- This is the code where I'm trying to delete -->
            "<a href='#itemList' onclick='deleteItem("+snapshot.key+")'>Delete</a>" +
            "</li><br/>";

    });

}

function deleteItem(itemToDelete) {
    //Just using console.log to make sure each key is being referenced
    console.log(itemToDelete);
}
```

It recognises the key that I want when I select the 'delete' link but  returns the error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: KfMB_sYMvARj1apJwST is not defined.

I've tried using appendChild() as well to add an identifier without success. This looked something like:

```
    snapshot.key.appendChild(identfier);
```

Where identifier is just a variable starting at 0 and looping through each item in a for loop. This triggered an error in Firebase.js and I guessed it was because it was trying to do this asynchronously so I stored the keys in an array first and then tried using appendChild() to add to each item in the array but got the same error back as well. I've watched videos of this type of app being built in iOS, Angular, Android but I just can't seem to find any native javascript solutions to get it to work or successfully adapt the solutions from other languages.

I'm still a bit of an amateur at coding with Javascript, while I can make a list app thats offline and can add/ edit/ delete simply enough - doing the same with data from Firebase feels very confusing. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: try: `onclick='deleteItem(\""+snapshot.key+"\")'` -- you didn't wrap the value in quotes.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh That worked, thank you so much! This had been driving me crazy.